# Unable to get the expected result for merging the array inside of an array of objects in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am having an array consists of 2 objects and each object again consists of an array of objects. I need to combine those inside array of objects.
please find the code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export const data = [
  {
    accountNo: '1xxx',
    consolidateddata: [
      { name: 'Paypal', expiry: '05/13/2023' },
      { name: 'phonepay', expiry: '05/19/2023' },
    ],
  },
  {
    accountNo: '2xxx',
    consolidateddata: [{ name: 'Paytm', expiry: '05/25/2023' }],
  },
];
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DataRows: [],
    };
    this.ProfileDetails = this.ProfileDetails.bind(this);
  }

  ProfileDetails = (profileData, index) => {
    const newData =
      profileData.consolidateddata &&
      profileData.consolidateddata.map((obj) => {
        return obj;
      });
    this.setState({ DataRows: newData });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    data && data.forEach(this.ProfileDetails);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.DataRows);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>sample</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

currently I am getting only one object(second row object array) in an array instead of 3 objects. can anybody suggest on this to get 3 combined objects like this

```
[ { name: 'Paypal', expiry: '05/13/2023' },
{ name: 'phonepay', expiry: '05/19/2023' }, { name: 'Paytm', expiry: '05/25/2023' } ]
```

stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-drpgcx?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 3):

you could try using reduce inside your function

something like

```js
const getAllData = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const {consolidateddata} = val
    acc = acc.concat(...consolidateddata)
    return acc
  },[])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you do not understand how react setState works and inmutability

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataRows: [],
    };
  }

  setProfileDetails = () => {
    this.setState({ dataRows: data.reduce((acc, val) => {
      const {consolidateddata} = val
      acc = acc.concat(...consolidateddata)
      return acc
    },[]) });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setProfileDetails()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ol>
          {this.state.dataRows.map((d) => {
            return (
              <li key={d.expiry}>
                {`${d.name} - ${d.expiry}`}
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

try to learn those concepts before